# How to get back the XCode dialog that was shown when I attempted to edit a locked file?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, perforce, xcode4.4

I am using Perforce with XCode 4.4, and these two seem to to be somewhat incompatible.

Perforce seems to be locking files, and XCode normally shows a dialog when you attempt to edit a locked file, asking whether you'd like to unlock it.

I dismissed this dialog, but now I have to manually press the unlock button in the top-right hand corner.

Does anyone know how to get this automatic dialog back so that it shows the dialog is I start typing in the locked file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article describing how to use XCode behaviors to solve the problem:

http://kb.perforce.com/article/1735/automatically-checking-out-files-for-edit-in-xcode-43

Comment: Very useful article, but not the actual answer I was looking for